# How to order a list of objects alphabetically?

Tags: python, sorting, alphabetical

How can I sort a list of objects alphabetically without using any python-metods?
For instance for a class Student with attributes Name, Grade I tried writing the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
for i in range (0, len(studentList)-1):
    if studentList[i].getName() > studentList[i+1].getName():
        aux = studentList[i].getName()
        studentList[i].getName() = studentList[i+1].getName()
        studentList[i+1].getName() = aux
```

Comment: Have you researched any sorting algorithms at all?

Comment: This code will cause exception - for the last i value (hate one-letter ids) it will throw an exception

Comment: I know bubble sort, selection sort, quick sort and merge sort, but the incorrect lines are  studentList[i].getName() = studentList[i+1].getName()
                studentList[i+1].getName() = aux

Comment: @volcano: No, because the range is limited to `len(studentList) - 1`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, exactly. *len(studentList) - 1* will give **the very last index**  in the list

Comment: @volcano: No, because `range()` produces a list of integers that *excludes*  the end point.

Comment: Opps, sorry, you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to assign to the result of the `.getName()` call, which is not going to work all too well. Use `studentList[i]` and `studentList[i + 1]` *directly*; you only need the `.getName()` call results to compare the student names:

```
aux = studentList[i]
studentList[i] = studentList[i+1]
studentList[i+1] = aux
```

To swap two items in your list, just use multiple assignment (no need for an extra temporary variable):

```
studentList[i], studentList[i+1] = studentList[i+1], studentList[i]
```

Without some more thought into the sorting algorithm, your simple loop will not, of course, result in a full sort.

Comment: is it the main problem of this sorting algo? it was better as a comment

Comment: The loop - as it is - is endless

Comment: @AndyT: The main problem blocking the OP is the assignment issue. The lack of sorting algorithm is the next hurdle.

Comment: @volcano: The `while True:` was removed early on.

Comment: It's not the sorting the issue, but the assignment

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is use bubblesort:

```
def bubble_sort(list_of_students):
    """
    Runs the bubble sort algorithm on the student class
    @rtype : list
    @param list_of_students: List of students to be sorted
    @type list_of_students: list
    """
    for _ in list_of_students:
        for j in xrange(len(list_of_students) - 1):
            if list_of_students[j] > list_of_students[j + 1]:
                list_of_students[j + 1], list_of_students[j] = list_of_students[j], list_of_students[j + 1]

    return list_of_students
```

Try the following:

```
from random import randint, choice
import string


class Student(object):
    def __init__(self, name, grade):
        self.name = name
        self.grade = grade

    def __gt__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Student):
            return self.name > other.name
        raise Exception("Cannot compare Student to Not-A-Student")

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{name} => {grade}".format(name=self.name, grade=self.grade)


def bubble_sort(list_of_students):
    """
    Runs the bubble sort algorithm on the student class
    @rtype : list
    @param list_of_students: List of numbers to be sorted
    @type list_of_students: list
    """
    for _ in list_of_students:
        for j in xrange(len(list_of_students) - 1):
            if list_of_students[j] > list_of_students[j + 1]:
                list_of_students[j + 1], list_of_students[j] = list_of_students[j], list_of_students[j + 1]

    return list_of_students


l = [Student(choice(string.ascii_uppercase), randint(0, 10)) for i in range(10)]
print bubble_sort(l)
```